# ViewPager tabs handling

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I have some problems with rendering of pages of a ViewPager with Tabs into the ActionBar.
Example:
[image: Example image]

Android info: minimum API 19, compile API 21 (Using AppCompat)

Main layout (main.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.MainFragment">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainFragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
private ViewPager viewPager;
private PagerTabsAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
private String[] tabs;
private int startIn;

MainActivity main;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    main = (LessonsScheduler) getArguments().get("instance");
    tabs = new String[]{"1","2","3"};
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    if(!main.getSupportActionBar().isShowing())
        main.getSupportActionBar().show();

    viewPager = (ViewPager) main.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = main.getSupportActionBar();

    // Getting item array
    mAdapter = new PagerTabsAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), main.getGroups());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    actionBar = main.getSupportActionBar();
    //Enable Tabs on Action Bar
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener(){
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        }
    };
    if (actionBar.getTabCount() == 0) {
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(tabListener));

        }
    }
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}
}
```

When i click tab buttons my viewpager doesn't change. I already tested invalidate(), requestLayout(), forceLayout() but these doesn't works.

Line of code to test:

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
```

Comment: Just to be curious, why didn't you used `tabLayout`?

Comment: Because seems `TabLayout` can be used only on `API 22+`

Comment: Nope. there is no such things. Check out this tutorial .. https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout#design-support-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I'm using **TabLayout** (thanks @Wizard). It seems to work with old APIs.

I'm still open for new ideas.